# Ios TapGestures

Tags: ios, swift

Im experimenting on tap gestures

I'm trying to add a tap gesture to a view but when the click occurs I get an error

here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TapPageHandler")

    myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func TapPageHandler(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    print("hello world")
}
}
```

and the error I get is:

2016-05-14 20:08:47.753 TapGestureTest[6641:245475] -[TapGestureTest.ViewController TapPageHandler]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc1fb58f430
2016-05-14 20:08:47.813 TapGestureTest[6641:245475] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TapGestureTest.ViewController TapPageHandler]:

can anyone guide me through this? and tell why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

You are having different selector signature and method signature (Your method signature expects a parameter and your selector signature expects a method with no parameter).

You need to specify the selector like:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TapPageHandler:")
```

Answer (score 1):

action: "TapPageHandler" should be action: "TapPageHandler:", the : defines that it will be expecting a argument.